# How to show the sum of two numbers that are computed dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I saw this code on stackoverflow that computes two numbers from input fields and shows the sum in another text field

javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function calculate(){
    var x=parseInt(document.getElementById("first").value);
    var y=parseInt(document.getElementById("second").value);
    document.getElementById("answer").value=(x+y);
    }
    </script>
```

Body

```
    First:<input id="first" name="first" type="text"><br>
    Second:<input id="second" name="second" type="text"><br>
    Answer:<input id="answer" name="answer" type="text"><br>
    <input onclick="calculate()" type="button" value="Addition">
```

When I tried to change the answer input field into a `<span id="answer">`, the answer does not show. Is there anyway that I can show it as a `<span>` or a heading?

Comment: use document.getElementById("answer").textContent for that

Comment: If you change the input into span, then you can't assign value by `element.value` but by using `element.innerHTML`

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadasjad/t1dovxwg/3/

```
First:<input id="first" name="first" type="text"><br>
    Second:<input id="second" name="second" type="text"><br>
    Answer:<input id="answer" name="answer" type="text"><br>
    <input onclick="return calculate();" type="button" value="Addition">


calculate = function(){
    var x=parseInt(document.getElementById("first").value);
    var y=parseInt(document.getElementById("second").value);
    var ans=(x+y)
    document.getElementById("answer").value=ans;
    }
```

Comment: OP wants to have output in `span`

Comment: just use innerHTML in place of value with that element id: https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadasjad/t1dovxwg/6/

Answer (score 1):

> `DOM` object returned by `getElementById(ID_OF_TE_SPAN_ELEMENT)` does not have `value` property.

To set the text of span/div, use `element.innerText`

Try this:

```js
function calculate() {
  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("first").value);
  var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("second").value);
  document.getElementById("answer").innerText = (x + y);
}
```

```html
First:
<input id="first" name="first" type="text">
<br>Second:
<input id="second" name="second" type="text">
<br>Answer:
<span id="answer"></span>
<input onclick="calculate()" type="button" value="Addition">
```

**Edit:** As suggested by [mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan), Use `.innerHTML` for greater backwards compatibility(IE < 6). As per the [[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText)], *`innerText` feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track* but have never faced any issue with this yet. `.textContent` could be used as well but consider *Browser compatibility*

Comment: or innerHTML for greater backwards compatibility

Comment: Actually innerText was supported by IE first. It is FireFox that was slow to pick it up: http://quirksmode.org/dom/html/

Comment: @mplungjan, Never though if this..We always relate _compatibility with IE_ ;)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function findingTotal()
    {
        var arr = document.getElementsByName('field');
        //alert(arr.length);
        var tot=0;
        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
                tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
        }
        document.getElementById('total_sum').value = tot;
    }
```

```html
<h2>sum of dynamic input fields By NAME<h2>

Field-1 : <input onblur="findingTotal()" type="text" name="field" id="field_1"/><br>
Field-2 : <input onblur="findingTotal()" type="text" name="field" id="field_2"/><br>
<br>
Total : <input type="text" name="total_sum" id="total_sum"/>
```

Comment: Could you add this as real code inside you answer? Also an explanation for that would be good.